# Bootstrap HTML5 Document Outline Algorithm

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a website with bootstrap and native HTML5 tags. However, I'm running into several issues.

Take [this website](http://themeforces.com/demo/freebies/tf-free-no.3/) as an example. If you are viewing this with the Google Chrome [Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-outliner/afoibpobokebhgfnknfndkgemglggomo) you can see that there are two untitled things:

[image: Untitled]

This is caused by the following HTML:

```
<!-- Navigation
==========================================-->
<nav id="tf-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Spirit8</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#tf-home" class="page-scroll">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tf-about" class="page-scroll">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tf-team" class="page-scroll">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tf-services" class="page-scroll">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tf-works" class="page-scroll">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tf-testimonials" class="page-scroll">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tf-contact" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

But this website is built with Bootstrap and is using the the default bootstrap [markup](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/).

What is going on here and how can the code be adjusted to generate a correct outline? Bootstrap does not need a heading inside `<header>` or `<nav>`, so what is the correct behaviour to generate a correct outline for SEO purposes?

Answer (score 1):

You have no heading elements to title those sections. That is why they are listed as "Untitled". If you put a `<h1>Headline</h1>` in the body or in the nav, you'll see the change.

Comment: Of course but this is by design. The heading of the page in bootstrap is .navbar-brand. So I don't need another heading. Should I create a heading and then hide it? I don't think this is SEO friedly

Comment: @julmot .navbar-brand may have the words of a heading but, unless it's an actual <hx> element, it won't change the outline or the structure of your page. What bootstrap does means nothing to your document or its outline.

Comment: But I think for SEO purposes it is a problem to have an untitled body or untitled nav. However, as you know, there is no need for an <hx>-element in bootstrap. So what is the workaround?

Comment: That's a longer discussion. Browsers do not implement the HTML5 outline, as they should, so search engines aren't either. SEO is off-topic on SO. If bootstrap has no need for heading elements, it's reason #1374 why I don't, and won't, use it.

Comment: What should browsers implement? It's up to the developer to design headings that they will look like a h1-h6 even if they are all h1 nested in some sections.

Comment: @julmot It's described in the spec. They just don't do it yet.